# Buffer overflow prevention using NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to understand how does NSString class help in preventing buffer overflow problem in Object ive C.can any one give me an example how is NSString class preventing it.

Thanks in advance 
Divya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below example shows overflow, because in loop each time it goes on increasing, that means it goes beyond the memory buffer limit,thts why it shows overflow.

```
int count = 2147483647;
NSString *str = @"";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    @try { 
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];//NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", str , @"\n"
    }
    @catch (NSException *exceptions) {
        NSLog(@"end after %d loops (%@)", i, [exceptions description]);
    }
}
```

[see this link to more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906438/nsstring-overflows-its-buffer-and-app-crashed-debugger-doesnt-see-any-stack-tr)

Comment: How big did your string get? I've worked with NSStrings as large as 13GB without running into any issues at all.

Comment: stringByAppendingString returns an autoreleased string, so this is actually using way more memory (roughly i^2/2 more) than the current length of str, because the all the created strings won't be released till after the runloop.